# How to access formControl name dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to get the value of a formControl by passing the control name as a function argument?

```
destructCityAndStreetFromObject(type: string) {
    let form: FormGroup = (this.section2Form.controls.formControlBuilderinputs as FormGroup)
    let Val = form.controls.`${type}`.value.value;
}
```

Comment: Is `type` the name of the `formControl` (value of `formControlName`)?

Comment: if `type` is the name of the `formControl` then you should just try:
let Val = form.controls[type].value;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function destructCityAndStreetFromObject(type: string) {
 const form = (this.section2Form.controls.formControlBuilderinputs as FormGroup)
 const ctrlType = form.controls[type];
 if(ctrlType){
  const {value:{value: Val}} = ctrlType;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
form.get("control_name")
```

Comment: This works together with the Typescript option `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors:"false"`

Answer (score 0):

```
let ctrlName = "myControl";    
form.controls[ctrlName].value = ctrlName;
```